# Conditional Expectation: modern and classical definitions

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I've just taken a course in modern probability theory following William's *Probability with Martingales*. On a separate venture, I started reading Hastie's *The Elements of Statistical Learning*. As I never took a statistics course, I'm having a bit of trouble conciliating different definitions of conditional expectation.

On Hastie, it is claimed that the expected prediction error
$$\text{EPE}(f) = E(Y-f(X))^2$$
can also be written as
$$\text{EPE}(f) = E_X E_{Y | X}((Y-f(X))^2 | X). $$
Now, I'm not quite sure what the right hand side means.
This seems to be an application of the tower property
$$\text{E}(X | \mathcal{H}) = \text{E}(\text{E}(X | \mathcal{G}) | \mathcal{H}), $$
where $\mathcal{G}$ is a sub $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{H}$, but I'm not quite able to translate everything back and forth.

To be concrete: what does $\text{E}_X$ and $\text{E}_{Y|X}$ mean, and how can I phrase the identity above for the EPE in terms of the modern definition of conditional expectation?

Comment: [This section of the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_random_variable_2) may be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $$\text{EPE}(f) = E(Y-f(X))^2$$ can also be written as
>   $$\text{EPE}(f) = E_X E_{Y | X}((Y-f(X))^2 \mid X). $$
>   Now, I'm not quite sure what the right hand side means.
>   This seems to be an application of the tower property

That it is.   You may safely ignore the "training wheels" subscripts.   They are meant as helpful reminders evoking a double integral's bounds, but, in practice, seem to confuse the issue more often than they help.   You are dealing with plain:

$$\text{EPE}(f) ~{=~E\big((Y-f(X))^2\big) \\[1ex] =~ E \Big(E\big((Y-f(X))^2 \mid X\big)\Big) }$$

In short: $\mathsf E(g(X,Y)) = \mathsf E(\mathsf E(g(X,Y)\mid \sigma(X)))$, the expectation of a function of two(or more) random variables equals the expectation
of the conditional expectation of the function measured over (the sigma-algebra of) one of them.

The text has expressed it directly as the double expectation, most likely because it they will be using a double integral (or sum) to evaluate it down the line.

Comment: As you said, I was just confused by the subscripts. This sorts it out perfectly. Thanks!